# jQuery: Unique Each() var append

Tags: jquery, append, each, var

I'm appending some buttons from an XML-file, into some divs. Each div has one or two buttons in them.

In each Each(), append the buttons through a var. But after each button insert, the Each() overwrites the var.

How can I make a unique var, for each append??

It's the "buttonMarkup" I would like to have, as unique vars, so they don't overwrite eachother...

```
$(this).find('button', this).each(function(index) {
    var type = $(this).attr("type");
    var label = $(">label", this).text();
    var wunLink = $(">link", this).text();
    buttonMarkup = "<a href='" + wunLink + "' class='" + type + "'><span>" + label + "</span></a>";
});
```

How do I do this??

Thank you in advance... :-)

Comment: FYI, the [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) method only takes one argument. `$(this).find('button')` is the equivalent of `$('button', this)`. However, the former is ofter preferred. Also, shouldn't HTML attributes have double quotes?

Comment: Can we see the bit of code where you use buttonMarkup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just a + to the equal and it will concatenate the string

```
$(this).find('button', this).each(function(index) {
    var type = $(this).attr("type");
    var label = $(">label", this).text();
    var wunLink = $(">link", this).text();
    buttonMarkup += "<a href='" + wunLink + "' class='" + type + "'><span>" + label + "</span></a>";
});
```

so then you will have one long string in buttonMarkup that you can use to append(buttonMarkup)

Comment: I did this, and added "buttonMarkup = ''" before the whole each function. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could create an array:

```
var buttonMarkup = [];

$(this).find('button').each(function(index) {
    var type = $(this).attr("type");
    var label = $(this).children("label").text();
    var wunLink = $(this).children("link").text();
    buttonMarkup.push("<a href='" + wunLink + "' class='" + type + "'><span>" + label + "</span></a>");
});
```

or just append to the variable:

```
buttonMarkup += "<a href='...";
```

Also note that it should be `$(this).find('button').each(...`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're dealing with one big string, you can just concatenate, like this:

```
$(this).find('button').each(function(index) {
    var type = $(this).attr("type");
    var label = $(">label", this).text();
    var wunLink = $(">link", this).text();
    buttonMarkup += "<a href='" + wunLink + "' class='" + type + "'><span>" + label + "</span></a>";
});
```

Or, if you want separate variables I recommend an array you can add ([`.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)) to and manage, like this:

```
var buttonMarkupArray = [];
$(this).find('button').each(function(index) {
    var type = $(this).attr("type");
    var label = $(">label", this).text();
    var wunLink = $(">link", this).text();
    buttonMarkupArray.push("<a href='" + wunLink + "' class='" + type + "'><span>" + label + "</span></a>");
});
```

For example turning this into a string is just a simple [`.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join), like this:

```
var buttonMarkup = buttonMarkupArray.join('');
```

---

You can also clean up your selectors further than the above by using [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) which will use the native selector engine better, like this:

```
var buttonMarkupArray = [];
$(this).find('button').each(function(index) {
    var type = $(this).attr("type");
    var label = $(this).find("label").text();
    var wunLink = $(this).find("link").text();
    buttonMarkupArray.push("<a href='" + wunLink + "' class='" + type + "'><span>" + label + "</span></a>");
});
```

or even better using [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/), like this:

```
var buttonMarkupArray = $(this).find('button').map(function() {
    var type = $(this).attr("type");
    var label = $(this).find("label").text();
    var wunLink = $(this).find("link").text();
    return "<a href='" + wunLink + "' class='" + type + "'><span>" + label + "</span></a>";
}).get();
```